# Conditional import

Tags: conditionals

I'm making Test sheet.
Let I have a lot of .tex files.
And each .tex files are consist of question, points, date.

For example,
file1.tex -> question, 1 point, 2020-1-01 
file2.tex -> question, 1 point, 2020-1-12 
file3.tex -> question, 2 point, 2021-2-12 
file4.tex -> question, 2 point, 2021-3-3

What I want is making different version of test paper easily.
version 1 : only contains question
version 2 : only contains question which is 2 points.

[image: file list]
[image: file1]
[image: file2]

Comment: So the points should be contained in the file itself. What exactly is the format of your subfiles? Or can we decide which format we'd like?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I think of file like this.

\begin{question}
question
\end{question}
point=3
date=2020-1-12

Comment: May I suggest another format: `\begin{question}[point=3,date=2020-1-12] ...\end{question}`. This way the `question` environment can just evaluate its key=value list for `point` or `date` and act accordingly.

Comment: but I have no idea that my format is feasible.
If you have some recommendations, I'm so grateful.

Comment: Wow, your format is very simple and it fit to what I want.
If you don't mind , could you show some example about conditional import??

Comment: can you make a file list as you show in the question, but in tex syntax, say `\q{file1}{1}{2020-1-01} \q{file2}{1}{2020-1-12}...` then it would be easy to (say) input all the 2 point questions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I upload my file list. I hope it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following defines a `question` environment that will check its key=value input with the keys `date` and `points` and compare those to some filter list you can define.

The filter list accepts the keys `include` and `exclude`. If you use `include` without a value the initial behaviour is to include all questions, if you use `exclude` without a value all questions are excluded.

Both `include` and `exclude` accept a value as well, the value can contain `points` and `date`. You can use these keys arbitrary often, which will add a rule to the filter list. And both can be used with either `=` (just those matching), `>=` (those with equal or more points/that date or later), and `<=` (those with equal or less points/that date or earlier). As a special key both `include` and `exclude` accept `all`, which will clear the filter list and include/exclude all questions.

If you use `include` with a value *before* you used `include` without a value or `exclude` (with or without), this means that all questions are excluded except those matching the rules in the given value. The same is true for `exclude` (all included except those matching the rules).

So for instance

```
\questionFilter{exclude={points<=2, date<=2019-12-31}}
```

means that all questions are included except those giving two or less points, or those being older than 2020-01-01.

You can also change filter rules mid-document, if you want to.

The `question` environment itself will gobble its contents if its `points` and/or `date` don't match the filter rules. The gobbling is done by typesetting its contents into a box that isn't output.

You'll most likely want to tailor the code in `\question@start` and `\question@end` to your needs to get the output you want.

For new questions the `points` default to 0, and the `date` defaults to 0000-00-00.

The result of all of this is, that it doesn't matter whether a `question` is in a file or in your main document, since the exclusion is done on an environment basis.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{expkv-def}

\makeatletter
% initial values of internals
\let\question@\relax
\newcommand*\question@check@{}

% internals for the filter definition 
\newcommand\question@check[1]
  {%
    \edef\question@check@
      {%
        \unexpanded\expandafter{\question@check@#1}%
        {\unexpanded\expandafter{\question@action}}%
      }%
  }
\newcommand*\question@datetonum[1]
  {\numexpr\expandafter\question@datetonum@#1\relax}
\def\question@datetonum@#1-#2-{31*(12*#1+#2)+}
\newcommand*\question@check@points[4]
  {\ifnum\question@points#1#2 #3#4\fi}
\newcommand*\question@check@date[4]
  {\ifnum\question@datetonum\question@date#1\question@datetonum{#2} #3#4\fi}

% key=value setup for the filter
\ekvdefinekeys{qh23570filter-internal}
  {
     code  date    = \question@check{\question@check@date={#1}{}}
    ,code  date   >= \question@check{\question@check@date<{#1}\else}
    ,code  date   <= \question@check{\question@check@date>{#1}\else}
    ,code  points  = \question@check{\question@check@points={#1}{}}
    ,code  points >= \question@check{\question@check@points<{#1}\else}
    ,code  points <= \question@check{\question@check@points>{#1}\else}
    ,noval all     = \let\question@check@\@empty\question@action
  }
\ekvdefinekeys{qh23570filter}
  {
     noval include = \let\question@check@\@empty\let\question@\question@start
    ,code  include =
      \ifx\question@\relax\let\question@\question@remove\fi
      \def\question@action{\let\question@\question@start}%
      \questionFilter@{#1}%
    ,noval exclude = \let\question@check@\@empty\let\question@\question@remove
    ,code  exclude =
      \ifx\question@\relax\let\question@\question@start\fi
      \def\question@action{\let\question@\question@remove}
      \questionFilter@{#1}%
  }
\ekvletkv{qh23570filter-internal}{date>}  {qh23570filter-internal}{date >}
\ekvletkv{qh23570filter-internal}{date<}  {qh23570filter-internal}{date <}
\ekvletkv{qh23570filter-internal}{points>}{qh23570filter-internal}{points >}
\ekvletkv{qh23570filter-internal}{points<}{qh23570filter-internal}{points <}
\ekvsetdef\questionFilter{qh23570filter}
\ekvsetdef\questionFilter@{qh23570filter-internal}

% key=value setup for the environment
\ekvdefinekeys{qh23570question}
  {
     store   points = \question@points
    ,initial points = 0
    ,store   date   = \question@date
    ,initial date   = 0000-00-00
  }
\ekvsetdef\question@kv{qh23570question}
\newenvironment{question}[1][]
  {%
    \ifx\question@\relax
      \PackageError{question}{Initial behaviour unset. Defaulting to include}{}%
      \global\let\question@\question@start
    \fi
    \question@kv{#1}%
    \question@check@
    \question@
  }
  {\question@end}
\newcommand*\question@remove
  {%
    \setbox0\vbox\bgroup
    \edef\question@end{\unexpanded\expandafter{\question@end\egroup}}%
    \question@start
  }

% TODO: Add the start and end code you need for questions that are included here
\newcommand*\question@start{\par\bigskip\section{Question}}
\newcommand*\question@end{}
\makeatother

% just to create many questions with less effort
\newcommand\testquestion[2]
  {%
    \begin{question}[points=#1, date=#2]
      This is a question giving #1 points and created on #2.
    \end{question}
  }

% set the rules which questions are used
\questionFilter
  {
     include={points >= 2, points <= 0}
    ,exclude={points = 3, date <= 2020-10-09}
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{question}[points=15, date=2021-12-04]
  Does this answer your question?
\end{question}

% just to create many questions with less effort
\testquestion{0}{2020-10-08}
\testquestion{1}{2020-10-08}
\testquestion{2}{2020-10-08}
\testquestion{3}{2020-10-08}
\testquestion{4}{2020-10-08}
\testquestion{0}{2020-10-09}
\testquestion{1}{2020-10-09}
\testquestion{2}{2020-10-09}
\testquestion{3}{2020-10-09}
\testquestion{4}{2020-10-09}
\testquestion{0}{2020-10-10}
\testquestion{1}{2020-10-10}
\testquestion{2}{2020-10-10}
\testquestion{3}{2020-10-10}
\testquestion{4}{2020-10-10}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn’t have done it without you.  I really appreciate everything you’ve done. Thanks you so so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to filter questions with the package `dbshow`. Questions with dates and points are save to a database named `ques-db`. Then you can display them with custom filters and styles.

[image]

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dbshow}

\dbNewDatabase{ques-db}{
  ques  = tl,
  date  = date,
  point = int,
}
\begin{dbFilters}{ques-db}
  \dbNewConditional{point-cond}{point}{\dbval > 2}
  \dbNewConditional {date-cond}{date} {\dbval > 2022/01/01}
\end{dbFilters}
\dbNewStyle{base-style}{ques-db}{
  before-code     = \section{All Questions},
  item-code       = {%
    \par\noindent\dbuse{date}~(\dbuse{point} points)
    \par\noindent\dbarabic.~\dbuse{ques},
  },
  item-after-code = \medskip,
}
\dbNewStyle[base-style]{point-style}{ques-db}{
  before-code = \section{Questions with Points Greater than 2},
  raw-filter  = point-cond,
}
\dbNewStyle[base-style] {date-style}{ques-db}{
  before-code = \section{Questions after 2022/01/01},
  raw-filter  = date-cond,
}
\dbNewStyle[base-style]  {mix-style}{ques-db}{
  before-code = \section{Questions with Mix Conditionals},
  raw-filter  = {point-cond && date-cond},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{dbitem}{ques-db}[date=2022/01/01, point=2]
  \dbsave{ques}{$x + y =$}
\end{dbitem}

\begin{dbitem}{ques-db}[date=2022/01/02, point=1]
  \dbsave{ques}{$z^2 =$}
\end{dbitem}

\begin{dbitem}{ques-db}[date=2022/01/03, point=3]
  \dbsave{ques}{$x / \alpha =$}
\end{dbitem}

\dbshow {base-style}{ques-db}
\dbshow{point-style}{ques-db}
\dbshow {date-style}{ques-db}
\dbshow  {mix-style}{ques-db}

\end{document}
```